# How to solve IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following piece of code:

```
s = output.set_index('name')['col1']
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).stack().reset_index()
```

The second line raises an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I just want to understand why it happens?

The `s.index` returns:

```
Index(['100100', '100200', '100300'], dtype='object', name='name')
```

The `s.values.tolist()` returns:

```
[
 [],
 [],
 []
]
```

**Update:**

This is an example of `s`. It should be a starting point.

```
      col1
a     []
b     []
c     []
d     ["c1","c2"]
```

When `col1` is empty in all rows, the code fails at `df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).stack().reset_index()`.

This code fails for me (python 3.7 and pandas 0.24.2):

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c'],
                 'col1': [[],[],[]]}).set_index('name')
s.col1.apply(pd.Series).stack().dropna().reset_index()
```

The goal is to get either empty DataFrame if all col1 values are [], or the following DataFrame (for the above-shown example of `s`):

```
df =

name  col1
d     c1
d     c2
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `df = pd.DataFrame(s)`? Also what is `s` here? Post raw data, code to recreate your structures.

Comment: I guess your col1 is empty..

Comment: @EdChum: Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

`s.values.tolist()` gives `[[], [], [], ['c1', 'c2']]`, which is not really what you want. I think you need `pd.Series` instead of `tolist`:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c','d','e'],
                 'col1': [[],[],[],['c1','c2'],['d','e','f']]}).set_index('name')
s.col1.apply(pd.Series).stack().dropna().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
+---+------+---------+----+
|   | name | level_1 | 0  |
+---+------+---------+----+
| 0 | d    |       0 | c1 |
| 1 | d    |       1 | c2 |
| 2 | e    |       0 | d  |
| 3 | e    |       1 | e  |
| 4 | e    |       2 | f  |
+---+------+---------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks. In the output I only need two columns `name` and `col1`. Also, what happens if all values are []. Does it return empty DataFrame?

Comment: `dropna()` removes those with values `[]`. You can rename your output, i.e: `df.rename(cols={0:'col1'})` and drop `level_1`.

Comment: Ok, I tested this solution. Got the same error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: It fails when I use `s = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c'], 'col1': [[],[],[]]}).set_index('name')`

Comment: runs OK with that data, returning empty data frame, on my computer, python 3.6 and pandas 0.23.4.

Comment: I have pandas 0.24.2 and python 3.7