# The line of code does not run in Python 3.7 and pandas 0.24.2

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code snippet:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c'],
                 'col1': [[],[],[]]}).set_index('name')
s.col1.apply(pd.Series).stack().dropna().reset_index()
```

It should output an empty DataFrame. But instead of it, this code raises the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

Could anybody help me please?

Update:

Please check [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55651588/how-to-solve-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range) in order to understand the context and see more details about what I want to get.

Comment: work fine on my side

Comment: @Wen-Ben: Which versions of python and pandas do you use?

Comment: I get an empty DF with three columns, no error.  I'm back on Python 3.4.5, so your *should* be okay on the later Python3 version.

Comment: I can confirm the very same problem with line 2 on Pandas 0.24.2 and Python 3.7.3. The error comes from ```stack()```, BTW.

Comment: @accdias: Cool! It means that this error is not a mystery of my machine:) Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Prune: I know. It's my question:)

Comment: I don't know if this have the same effect but ```s.col1.apply(pd.Series).dropna().reset_index().stack()``` work here.

Comment: ... and also this ```.col1.apply(pd.Series).stack([]).dropna().reset_index()```.

Comment: @accdias: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately the effect of your code samples is not the same. Your code returns DataFrame just without the column `col1`. But I want to get an empty DataFrame. It means that all "[]" should be treated as empty.

Comment: @Tatik, I see. I'm not an expert on Pandas yet but it seems that we need to pass something to ```stack()``` from version 0.24.2 to make it happy. We just need to figure it out what is that. :-)

Comment: @accdias: Well, just to notice that the original code shown in this question does the correct job when the version of python and pandas is different.

Comment: Maybe you should check if `s.col1.apply(pd.Series)` contains some none empty elements before applying `stack()...`

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to choose a different version of pandas and save yourself some time. From all the other comments and a bit of my own experimenting, it seems that there is some incompatibility. You can try your code snippet here: https://www.python.org/shell/
and verify that it works, just do `import pandas` first, obviously. If you want to check the version of the pandas module used in the Python REPL emulator do: `pandas.__version__`. Hope that eventually, you'll get a response that helps you.

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.23.3'
```